# Geneos selenium testing

Tags: selenium, xvfb, geneos

We have developed selenium script for testing of frames in our website .
We will be writing the healthcheck of frames in a txt file and displaying the health check o/p in geneos console .

The selenium script will be deployed in Prod unix box and o/p (txt file) will be in a directory from where it will be accessed by Geneos monitor and displayed on its console .

Problem is since it is a Prod unix box , no one is willing to install Xvfb and firefox on unix box which are pre-requisites for selenium to work .

Any work around for selenium to work without any installations on unix Prod box will be highly appreciated , Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you looking for. But would you consider to run your script off the production infra and have Geneos monitoring on that output ?